# How to delete all comments in ruamel.yaml?

Tags: python, yaml, ruamel.yaml

By default ruamel.yaml preserves all the comments. How can I disable this option? I want to delete all comments from a yaml file, and these comments can be anywhere.

Currently I check every element and set `yamldata.ca._items = {}`, but it doesn't always work. Sometimes it just removes comments before a line but not after. Also, it works only for the first level, and to remove comments in submaps I have to use a recursive function.

**Is there any simple way to just delete all comments?**

The pyyaml library doesn't keep comments, but it also doesn't allow to configure indentation and doesn't preserve order.
Deleting all lines with `#` from the file would also delete lines like `key: value # comment`.

Comment: You should include minimal working code, including  the part around `yamldata.ca._items = {}` that shows your problem, when posting on SO

Answer (score 1):

If you care about the ordering of keys, and are not still using Python 2 (you shouldn't),
then you can just use the safeloader to load and then dump using the (default) round-trip dumper:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
x: # first mapping
   b: 1
   a: 2
y:
   - 3
   - "4" # last_item
"""

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.indent(mapping=4, sequence=4, offset=2)
yaml.preserve_quotes = True
yaml.default_flow_style = False

data = ruamel.yaml.YAML(typ='safe').load(yaml_str)
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
x:
    b: 1
    a: 2
y:
  - 3
  - '4'
```

and as you can see the quotes around `4` have changed.

If that is unacceptable, you should load using the round-trip loader,
as you do, but instead only deleting the comment attributes `items`,
you should just delete the attribute holding the comments completely.

That can of course not be done using the `ca` property, you'll have to
delete the attribute itself. In case there is no comment, you actually
create an empty comment structure on all complex nodes that don't have
one when using `.ca` on them.

```
def recursive_delete_comment_attribs(d):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        for k, v in d.items():
            recursive_delete_comment_attribs(k)
            recursive_delete_comment_attribs(v)
    elif isinstance(d, list):
        for elem in d:
            recursive_delete_comment_attribs(elem)
    try:
         # literal scalarstring might have comment associated with them
         attr = 'comment' if isinstance(d, ruamel.yaml.scalarstring.ScalarString) \
                  else ruamel.yaml.comments.Comment.attrib 
         delattr(d, attr)
    except AttributeError:
        pass



data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
recursive_delete_comment_attribs(data)
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
x:
    b: 1
    a: 2
y:
  - 3
  - "4"
```